# How do you pass optional arguments to a Symfony2 service from a controller?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I am currently working on a project using Symfony2 and have come across a situation that I cannot figure out an answer for.

I have created a model that validates and uploads files. The way that I was originally instantiating the model was by doing something like this inside my controller.

```
$constraints = array('maxSize'=>'1M','mimeTypes' => array('application/pdf','application/x-pdf'));
$uploadFiles = new UploadModel($this->get('validator'), $request, $editForm->getName(), 'filePaths', $constraints);
```

However that didn't seem very "Symfony" like since there is a whole service layer. In fact after I ran the SensioLabs Insight tool it recommended that I not directly pass the validator and request services directly to the model, and instead inject them into the service. So now my files look like this.

### services.yml

( AE/CaseDesignBundle/Resources/config/services.yml )

```
ae_case_design.uploadmodel:
    class: AE\CaseDesignBundle\Models\UploadModel
    arguments: [ @validator, @request_stack ]
```

### UploadModel.php

( AE/CaseDesignBundle/Models/UploadModel.php )

```
public function __construct($validator, $requestStack, $formName, $fileInput, $constraints = null)
{
}
```

### CarrierController.php

( AE/CaseDesignBundle/Controller/CarrierController.php )

```
$constraints = array('maxSize'=>'1M','mimeTypes' => array('application/pdf','application/x-pdf'));
$uploadFiles = $this->get('ae_case_design.uploadmodel');
```

**The question I have now is how can I pass the remaining 3 arguments (2 strings and 1 array) to the UploadModel __construct?** I have seen some other examples where people have done something like this:

```
$constraints = array('maxSize'=>'1M','mimeTypes' => array('application/pdf','application/x-pdf'));
$uploadFiles = $this->get('ae_case_design.uploadmodel')->init($editForm->getName(), 'filePaths', $constraints);
```

However to me it seems weird that this is the only way to inject non-service level arguments into a __construct, because now I have to run a init() function before my service is ready to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change init to create and pretend your upload model is a factory.

```
$uploadFiles = 
    $this->get('ae_case_design.uploadmodel_factory')->create($editForm->getName(), 
        'filePaths', $constraints);
```

You don't actually need to have two classes, create can just returns $this but the semantics now make it clear that you would never use uploadmodel_factory by itself.  Of course if you really wanted to you could make it two classes in which the factory returns an uploadmodel class.

In addition, You could also consider having a ae_case_design.uploadmodel_factory.pdf service would would inject the constraints for you.  This would get rid of one of your arguments at least.